# Print linked list nodes one entry at a time (Java)

Tags: java, list, printing, linked-list

Any idea on how to print one entry at a time e.g Press enter to show next entry.
This is the printLink method:

```
//Print Link data
    public void printLink()
    {
            System.out.println("") ;
            System.out.print("Book Name: " + getBookName() + "\n" + "Book's Author: " + getBookAuthor() + "\n" + "Year Published: " + getPublicYear() + "\n" + "ISBN: " + getIsbn() +"\n");
            System.out.println("") ;
    }
```

This is the printList method:

```
//Prints list data
    public void printList()
    {
            Link currentLink = first;
            while(currentLink != null) {
                    currentLink.printLink();
                    currentLink = currentLink.nextLink;
            }
            System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for a user input after each print:

```
    public void printList()
    {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Link currentLink = first;
            while(currentLink != null) {
                    currentLink.printLink();
                    currentLink = currentLink.nextLink;
                    scan.next();
            }
            System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: is there any chance to limit the user's interaction to just pressing the enter button? without the need to input any character or such.

Comment: yes. `scan.nextLine()`. once enter is pressed, this method will return.